# Processing non uniform JSON in PIG Latin

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have sample JSON file

{"type":"Chrome","url":"www.example1.com","host":"HOST1","referer":"www.reference1.com"}
{"type":"FireFox","url":"www.example1.com","host":"HOST1","referer":"www.reference2.com"}
{"type":"Chrome","url":"www.example2.com","host":"HOST2"}

In the above JSON , referer field is not available in all records. it may or may not be available. How to process them in PIG Latin.

The below script able to process them if the fields are uniform in JSON and avaiable for all records. ( removed the record which doesn't have the referer field )

```
register '/usr/local/pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar';
record = LOAD 'piginput/file.json' 
USING JsonLoader('type:chararray,url:chararray,host:chararray,referer:chararray');
GroupByhttp = GROUP record BY (referer,type);
CountByhttp = FOREACH GroupByhttp 
GENERATE group,COUNT(record);
STORE CountByhttp
INTO 'pig_output';
```

Please advice !!

Comment: What happens when you try to process the non-uniform JSON?

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus  This the error i get when i try 
2014-02-20 20:33:11,474 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2014-02-20 20:33:11,510 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Current token (null) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7a4fe91e; line: 1, column: 175]